# Suppose a and b are real numbers, not both 0. Find real numbers c and d such that

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$\dfrac{1}{a+bi} = c+di$

I've tried to use vectors like this:

$\dfrac{1}{(a,b)} = (c,d)$

and calculated the matrix

\begin{bmatrix} a-c&a-d \\ b-d&b-d \end{bmatrix} = 0

But I've got the reciprocal again.

(sorry for the matrix, I don't know how to code it in MathJax)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could multiply top and bottom by the conjugate $a-bi$

Comment: Or you could invert the matrix $\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}$, which corresponds to $a+bi$

Comment: Sorry, the matrix I've calculated is actually \begin{bmatrix} ac & ad \\ bc & bd \end{bmatrix} = 0. So I can use your answer. \begin{bmatrix} ac & -ad \\ bc & bd \end{bmatrix} = 0 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Question : Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers not both of them equal to $0$. Find the real numbers $c$ and $d$ satisfying the equation $1/(a+ib)=c+id$.

Solution : We have $1/(a+ib)=c+id$ .  Now multiplying both numerator and denominator in LHS by $a-ib$, we get $a-ib/(a^2+b^2)=c+id$ $=>$   $a/(a^2+b^2)-ib/(a^2+b^2)=c+id$ .
Now comparing the real and imaginary parts in both LHS and RHS we get $c=a/(a^2+b^2)$ and $d=-b/(a^2+b^2)$. Now considering cases : If $a=0$ then $c=0$ and if $b=0$ then $d=0$ and $a$ and $b$ both cannot be zero so if both are non zero real numbers then $c$ and $d$ are also both non zero real both numbers .